# Simple steps to find why I don't have permission to "mv" a folder

Tags: permissions

I tried something normal:

```
$ mv path1 path2

mv: cannot move
'path1/subfolder/' to 'path2/subfolder': Permission denied
```

The `path2` doesn't initially exist, so this should replicate the folder tree of `path1` as `path2`. A `find path1 -ls` shows that I have read/write permission to all files and folders in `path1`.

An initial `diff -qr path1 path2` showed that `path1/subfolder` wasn't moved.  However, I can recursively *copy:*

```
mkdir path2/subfolder
cp -r path1/subfolder/* path2/subfolder

# Confirm that original subtree and copy are identical
diff -qr path1 path2 # Reveals that the two are identical
```

While I have worked around the problem, I am never happy with unexplained behaviour.  Is there is simple way to poke and prod for the cause?  I do mean simple, as I don't write Bash scripts.  I merely use it at the command line.

I am using Cygwin on Windows 10.  The account is a non-administrator account.  All files and folders are owned by the account.  I ensured that there are no zombie processes like Office apps or Matlab that might somehow be preventing a folder from being deleted, though the problem could just as easily be read access or something else.  As the workaround shows, it definitely isn't write access to the destination tree.  I can also `rm -r path1`, so the problem isn't write access to the original tree, either.

**Drat.**  That means I no longer have `path1`, which makes it hard to try out any troubleshooting suggestions.  I'm still open to suggestions, though.

Comment: Is `path1` and `path2` in the same directory or in two different places? If in two different places, are they also on two different devices? What are the permissions and ownerships of the directories that _contain_ `path1` and `path2`?

Comment: They are not in the same folder.  `path1` has a form `dirA/dirB/dirC` whereas `path2` has the form `dirD/dirE`.  Or something like that, I've reorganized since.  But both are on the same local SSD in `/home/MyUserName/dirE/dirF`.  I own all the folders and files under the tree rooted at `/home/MyUserName`.  I have read/write permissions for all files/folders, and additionally, execute permission for all folders.

Comment: If the source and target is on the same partition, then `mv` would not even touch anything beneath `path1` (it's just renaming the `path1` pathname to `path2`). I can't therefore see why it would be complaining about a sub-directory.

Comment: It's actually changing the location of the subtree rooted at `path1` to `path2`.  I get that this might just be some bookkeeping about where `path1` is located, and rightly or wrongly, I wouldn't expect it to recursively move each folder in the subtree.  Your question makes wonder what mistakes I've made in composing the question post hoc.  I did try to scroll upward in my *xterm*, but message was beyond the retention limit. If however, the error message as posted actually came from a subsequent attempt to `cp` or `mv` `path1/subfolder`, then that's where the problem was tracked down to.

Comment: If it was `cp` you did instead of `mv`, then it's a totally different story as the `cp` command _does_ need to traverse the whole tree that it's copying (if copying the whole hierarchy).

Comment: Then I'm at a complete loss.  On one hand, it seems like `mv` should have fewer barriers, if in fact it's just bookkeeping the root node `path1`.  In contrast, `cp` needs at least read permission, not just to a given file, but every component in the path, and execute permission for all folders.  On the other hand, there may be safeguards against shifting the (virtual) location of a file via `mv`.  Beyond a certain point, the file system is black magic to me.

Comment: Same issue. Win10. git-bash. Non-admin user account. Owner of all relevant dirs and subdirs. 
Trying to work around insane slowness of Win10 deletion of folders with deep subtrees, by simply moving them out of the way (to immediately free up the original path) then deleting from the new path as a 2nd step, via e.g.
`mv BIGDIR ~/trashme/ && rm -rf ~/trashme`

It's perfect when it works.
But in some cases (so far, unsure what's different), 

`mv ./common/temp ~/trashme`

results in:

`mv: cannot move 'common/temp' to '/c/Users/cweekly/trashme/temp': Permission denied`

Comment: elevated command prompt is required for moving symbolic links in windows 10

facepalm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason it should happen is if both of the following conditions are correct:

1. `path1` and `path2` are not on the same filesystem. You can check this by running `df path1` and `df path2` (or on their parent folders) and see they are not on the same partition. If they were both on the same partition, then the `mv` command wouldn't have tried to recursively move the entire directory tree; It would just rename `path1` to `path2`, without moving the child files and directories.
2. `path1` doesn't have write permission for the user or the group. You said you have read/write permission to all files and folders in `path1`, but if you want to move `path1` to another filesystem, you would need write permission to `path1` by itself (or to the parent of `subfolder`, if the `subfolder` is not a direct child or `path`).

Since you've already removed `path1`, we cannot confirm this now. You said that you were able to `rm` the folder after copying it, but you might have changed the permissions at some point in the middle, and I cannot prove this. But you wouldn't have had this problem.

In general, there's probably some detail you didn't tell us, something you might have missed or didn't think was relevant, but again - now it's impossible to confirm that. Especially since you've used `cp -r` (which does not preserve permissions, for that you would need `-a` or `-p`), so again, we cannot see what were the original permissions of all the files and folders.

Comment: Yes, I suspect you're right.  I tried scrolling upward on the *xterm*, but the actual session content was older than was was retained. But honestly, I'm 100% sure that I had read/write access to all files and folders, and execute access to all folders. All folders were created by me using Cygwin's Bash. There was one file in a leaf node folder that didn't have the complete set of pemissions (I forget the details), but the `mv` still failed after I corrected that.

Comment: The only possibility I can think of is that a zombie Windows or Office process was preventing a file from being moved, but I don't what mechanisms are used. While I'm not sure, I suspect that it isn't necessarily a hidden file in the folder of the locked file, at least one findable using `find`.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment but space is too limited.

> ```
> mv path1 path2
> ...
> cp -r path1/subfolder/* path2/subfolder
> ```

These are not the same thing. The former would create a new directory inside path2 with a name corresponding to the last directory name in path1, assuibg that it is a directory. The second would create a recurive copy of all the files in path1/subfilder/ in path2/subfilder.

It would have been helpful if you had provided the filesystem permissions and ownership of the things you are trying to manipulate, an indication of any mandatory access ontrol systems in place and examples of of how you expect the paths to lok before and after.

Comment: Actually, `path2` didn't exist beforehand, and I'll add that detail to the question.  That is why `path2` should come into existence and contain exactly the same files/folders as `path1`.  When I initially `diff`'d the source and destination paths, what wasn't moved was `subfolder`.  I will add that too. I did say that I owned all the files/folders and had read/write access. The only thing I'm unsure of now is whether I has "execute" permission on `subfolder`, but I was able to descend into it with the Bash shell and `less` files (and do a great many things actually).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows10, elevated permissions are required to create or mv symlinks.
If path1 contains symlinks -- even if they're owned by your non-admin user -- you'll get "permission denied" errors from `mv path1 path2`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991523/why-are-administrator-privileges-required-to-create-a-symlink-on-windows

Comment: Thanks, but I can create Windows shortcuts and Cygwin links (symbolic and not).  I've never had problems  with that over the years.  If I run into the problem again, I can examine the situational details more.